# CTE with recursion - row_number() aggregated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion

I have a table with a parent/child relationship along with a date created column referencing itself.
I want to display each parent record and all the descendants ordered by the most recent 'activity' on the node. 
So if row number 1 which was created a long time ago has a new child added to it (or a new child added to one its children for example), then I want it at the top of the results.

I'm having trouble getting this to work currently.

My table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [OrderId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Orders_OrderId] [int] NULL,
    [DateOrdered] datetime)
```

I have written the following SQL to pull the information out:

```
WITH allOrders AS 
   (SELECT po.orderid, po.Orders_OrderId, po.DateOrdered, 0 as distance,  
   row_number() over (order by DateOrdered desc) as RN1
    FROM orders po WHERE po.Orders_OrderId is null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b2.orderid ,b2.Orders_OrderId, b2.DateOrdered, c.distance + 1, 
    c.RN1
    FROM orders b2 
    INNER JOIN allOrders c 
    ON b2.Orders_OrderId = c.orderid
    )

SELECT * from allOrders
where RN1 between 0 and 2
order by rn1 asc, distance asc
```

Is there any way I can 'aggregate' the results of the recursive selects, so that I could select the maximum date across an entire 'parent' node?

SQLFiddle demonstration: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca6cb/11
(record number 1 should be first as it has a child that was updated recently)

**Update**
Thanks to the suggestion from @twrowsell I have the following query which *does* work but seems really clunky and has some performance issues, I feel I shouldn't have to have 3 CTE's to achieve this. Is there any way it can be condensed whilst preserving the 'row numbers' (as this is for a user display with paging)?

```
WITH allOrders AS 
  (SELECT po.orderid, po.Orders_OrderId, 0 as distance, po.DateOrdered, po.orderid as [rootId]
    FROM orders po WHERE po.Orders_OrderId is null 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b2.orderid ,b2.Orders_OrderId, c.distance + 1, b2.DateOrdered, c.[rootId]
    FROM orders b2     
    INNER JOIN allOrders c 
    ON b2.Orders_OrderId = c.orderid
    ),
    mostRecentOrders as (
    SELECT *,
    MAX(DateOrdered) OVER (PARTITION BY rootId) as [HighestOrderId]
    from allOrders
    ),
    pagedOrders as (
    select *, dense_rank() over (order by [HighestOrderId] desc) as [PagedRowNumber] from mostRecentOrders)

    SELECT  * from pagedOrders
    where PagedRowNumber between 0 and 2
    order by [HighestOrderId] desc
```

Also, I could use `MAX(orderid)` as orderid is the ident and datecreated can't be updated in my scenario after its created.

Updated SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca6cb/41

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @JonSenchyna SQL 2008

Comment: @EdW, Just show your desire output from given sample data in fiddle .

Comment: @KumarHarsh the second SQLFiddle has the correct data in it. I've added a bit more sample data here though http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9df5e/1

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to store the "root" order ID so that you can differentiate between different "trees" of orders.  Once you have that, you can aggregate and sort your data.

As far as I can tell, you will need at least one CTE to build the tree and a second to do the rankings since you can't use `DENSE_RANK()` in a `WHERE` clause.

The following query uses a temp table to store the tree.  The query selects from the tree twice, once for the rows and a second time for the rankings.  If I used a CTE for storing the tree, it would have to build it twice, since the CTE is basically just a reusable subquery (it would be rebuilt for each distinct time it is used).  Using a temp table ensures that I only need to build it once.

Here is the SQL:

```
DECLARE @Offset INT = 0;
DECLARE @Fetch INT = 2;

-- Create the Order Trees
WITH OrderTree AS (
  SELECT  po.orderid AS RootOrderID,
          po.orderid,
          po.Orders_OrderId,
          po.DateOrdered,
          0 AS distance
  FROM orders po WHERE po.Orders_OrderId IS NULL
  UNION/**/ALL
  SELECT  parent.RootOrderID,
          child.orderid,
          child.Orders_OrderId,
          child.DateOrdered,
          parent.distance + 1 AS distance
  FROM orders child
  INNER JOIN OrderTree parent
  ON child.Orders_OrderId = parent.orderid
)
SELECT *
INTO #OrderTree
FROM OrderTree;

-- Rank the order trees by MAX(DateOrdered)
WITH
Rankings AS (
    SELECT RootOrderID,
         MAX(DateOrdered) AS MaxDate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MAX(DateOrdered) DESC, RootOrderID ASC) AS Rank
  FROM #OrderTree
  GROUP BY RootOrderID
)
-- Get the next @Fetch trees, starting at rank @Offset+1
SELECT  TREE.*,
        R.MaxDate,
        R.Rank
FROM Rankings R
INNER JOIN #OrderTree TREE
    ON R.RootOrderID = TREE.RootOrderID
WHERE R.Rank BETWEEN @Offset+1 AND (@Fetch+@Offset)
ORDER BY R.Rank ASC, TREE.distance ASC;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84f18/13/0)

Note: The `/**/` between `UNION` and `ALL` is a workaround for [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185681/unable-to-post-any-answer-or-comment-with-union-all).

I built my own "orders" table using data in an existing table I had in my database and did some bench-marking against the 3-CTE query in the question. This slightly outperforms it on a large pool of data (117 trees with a total of 37215 orders, max depth of 11).  I benchmarked by running each query with `STATISTICS IO` and `STATISTICS TIME` turned on, clearing the cache and buffers before each run.

Below are the results of both queries, plus the results of the recursive CTE shared by both:

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦════════════╦══════════════╗
║ Query      ║ CPU Time ║ Scan Count ║ Logical Reads║
╠════════════╬══════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║ Tree CTE   ║ 24211ms  ║ 4          ║ 1116243      ║
╟────────────╫──────────╫────────────╫──────────────╢
║ 3-CTE      ║ 24789ms  ║ 7          ║ 1192221      ║
║ Temp Table ║ 24384ms  ║ 6          ║ 1116549      ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩════════════╩══════════════╝
```

It appears that the bulk of both of these queries is the recursive order-tree CTE.  Removing the shared cost of the recursive CTE gives the following results:

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦════════════╦══════════════╗
║ Query      ║ CPU Time ║ Scan Count ║ Logical Reads║
╠════════════╬══════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 3-CTE      ║ 578ms    ║ 3          ║ 75978        ║
║ Temp Table ║ 173ms    ║ 2          ║ 306          ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩════════════╩══════════════╝
```

**Based on these results, I highly recommend you add a RootOrderID column to your orders table to avoid having to use a potentially very costly recursive CTE.**

Answer (score 1):

Would using MAX on DateOrdered in an OVER clause in the outer select work..

```
    WITH allOrders AS 
(
    SELECT po.orderid, po.Orders_OrderId, po.DateOrdered, 0 as distance,  
       row_number() over (order by DateOrdered desc) as RN1
    FROM orders po WHERE po.Orders_OrderId is null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b2.orderid ,b2.Orders_OrderId, b2.DateOrdered, c.distance + 1, 
      c.RN1
    FROM orders b2 
    INNER JOIN allOrders c 
    ON b2.Orders_OrderId = c.orderid
    )


    SELECT *,   MAX(DateOrdered) OVER (PARTITION BY Orders_OrderId) from allOrders
    where RN1 between 0 and 2
    order by rn1 asc, distance asc
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry I misinterpreted your requirement first time. It looks like you want to partition your results by the RN1 field not Orders_OrderId so your outer select will be something like..

```
 SELECT MAX(DateOrdered) OVER (PARTITION BY RN1 ),*  from allOrders
where RN1 between 0 and 2
order by rn1 asc, distance asc
```

Comment: That doesn't work because Orders_OrderId doesn't uniquely identify a 'node', so it doesn't select the highest date of all the parent and children. It does give me a few ideas to work with though, so thanks

Comment: I did see that thanks @twrowsell, even though it was edited after I posted that in my question ;) it appears quicker to partition by a 'rootid' actually (which uniquely identifies each 'node'). I'm still looking for an improvement on the whole query, which is why I've added a bounty, perhaps I wasn't clear enough that I wanted to preserve paging in my original question.

Comment: @Maverick allOrders is the name of the CTE, defined on the first line. It's a recursive query

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following:

```
;WITH allOrders AS 
   (SELECT po.orderid, po.Orders_OrderId, po.DateOrdered, 0 as distance, po.orderid as [parentOrder]
    FROM orders po WHERE po.Orders_OrderId is null
        UNION ALL
    SELECT b2.orderid ,b2.Orders_OrderId, b2.DateOrdered, c.distance + 1, c.[parentOrder]
    FROM orders b2 
    INNER JOIN allOrders c ON b2.Orders_OrderId = c.orderid

    )
    SELECT a.OrderId
           ,a.Orders_OrderId
           ,a.DateOrdered
           ,top1.DateOrdered as HIghestDate
           ,a.distance
           ,a.parentOrder     
    FROM allOrders a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 2 parentOrder, MAX(DateOrdered)as highestdates FROM allOrders GROUP BY parentOrder ORDER BY MAX(DateOrdered)DESC)b on a.parentOrder=b.parentOrder 
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 parentOrder, DateOrdered FROM allOrders top1 WHERE a.parentOrder=top1.parentOrder ORDER BY top1.DateOrdered DESC)top1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca6cb/54)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding your exact full needs, including the paging situation. You could provide the expected result set for the sample you supplied, it would be easier to check against.

Anyway, it seems your main difficulty is on this:

> Is there any way I can 'aggregate' the results of the recursive
>   selects, so that I could select the maximum date across an entire
>   'parent' node?

... this can be easily done with that recursive CTE and an APPLY.

I'm not sure of what do you want exactly, so I made these two fiddles:

[SQL Fiddle 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca6cb/61) - Here all children are together based on the root order, i.e., order 3 is with its parent's (order 2) parent (order 1).

[SQL Fiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca6cb/58/0) - Here the children are grouped with their immediate parent, and also parents become roots, so order 2 doesn't get to the top with its parent (order 1).

I think you'll be going for some modification of the first one.

Again, it's really important to provide your expected result in questions like this one, or you'll get a lot of trial and error answers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the same resultset as what you had described in your updated fiddle. I reached my solution as part from pedro's cross apply.. just that apply is terrible in performance from my own experience. Eventually it evolved to what it currently is, a left join on the main table with a subquery that has the paging you requested.

Please find the fiddle [>>here (SQLFiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca6cb/98)

also, the code attached:

```
WITH allOrders AS (
  --anchor
  SELECT po.orderid
         , po.Orders_OrderId
         , 0 AS distance
         , po.DateOrdered
         , po.orderid AS [rootId]
  FROM orders po
  WHERE po.Orders_OrderId IS NULL

  --recursive
  UNION ALL

  SELECT b2.orderid
         , b2.Orders_OrderId
         , c.distance + 1
         , b2.DateOrdered
         , c.[rootId]
  FROM orders b2

    JOIN allOrders c
      ON b2.Orders_OrderId = c.orderid
)
SELECT a.*
       , b.max_orderdate
       , RN1
FROM allOrders a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT rootid, max(DateOrdered) max_orderdate 
           , row_number() over (order by max(dateordered) desc) as RN1
           FROM allOrders GROUP BY rootid) b
ON a.rootid = b.rootid
where RN1 between 0 and 2
ORDER BY b.max_orderdate DESC, a.rootid, a.orders_orderid, a.orderid
```

Comment: Why not use an `INNER JOIN`?  Also, since you're grouping on `rootid` in your subquery, `DISTINCT` is redundant.

Comment: @JonSenchyna you are absolutely right, distinct is redundant and I had it from a previous iteration of the code.. and I used left join out of habit. Inner Join would absolutely work too!